# I left my dogs sitting on another players island on a server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently left my dogs on another players island, sitting. Now, that player kicked me from the island and U need my dogs back ..is there a way to do it without commands or cheats?

Answer (score -1):

I don't really think so, but you should ask the guy who kicked you out, or possibly just make some new dogs.